# Disabling outlook desktop alert for a certain sender in powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook, alert, outlook-2010

I am trying to write a script that disables desktop alerts for a chosen sender address. I have done a lot of research but never found any specific code, so I thought I would try and write it myself. I was very optimistic about the code but it didn't work, I think I didn't understand a part of the outlook rules syntax in Powershell.

### My code so far

```
$olFolders = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders"
$outlook = New-Object -ComObject outlook.application
$namespace  = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")

$rules = $outlook.session.DefaultStore.GetRules()
$rule = $rules.create("New Rule: Disabling Alerts", [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlRuleType]::olRuleReceive)

$rule_Address = $rule.Conditions.SenderAddress
$rule_Address.Enabled = $true
$rule_Address.Address = "<Sender Adress>"
$action = $rule.Actions.DesktopAlert.Disabled
$action.Enabled = $false

$rules.save()
```

### The Problem

I can see in my outlook client app that the rule is added, but I tested it and the desktop alert is still shown.

### Extra question

Is it possible to create this rule and hide it in the outlook GUI? So that any other person can't see the rule in outlook client, so he/she can't disable the rule. If so, please help me out, this would come in very handy.

Comment: did you get any solution ? **Tools -> Options -> E-mail Options -> Advanced E-mail Options -> Desktop Alert Settings -> Preview**

Answer (score 0):

Sample here: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2009/12/16/hey-scripting-guy-can-i-use-windows-powershell-to-create-a-new-outlook-inbox-rule/

> Script to create a rule for "RSS feed" with "Desktop Alert". I took
>   Dan Jansson's script and modified to fit my needs:

```
 $DisplayAlert =  $rule.Actions.DesktopAlert
 $DisplayAlert.Enabled = $true
```